# Adding a character to vertically on column

Tags: awk, sed

Input:

```
dog
fish
elephant
...
```

Output:

```
dog     |
fish    |
elephant|
...     |
```

I want to add a "|" on the 9th character of every row

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: What if the input line contains nine or more characters?

Comment: 8 characters max

Comment: A one-liner: `awk '{ printf("%-8s|\n", $0) }' file`

Comment: Another one-liner in `sed`: `sed -E 's/$/        /; s/(.{8}).*/\1|/' file`

Comment: `xargs -a file printf '%-8s|\n'`

Answer (score 1):

You should first space pad the lines to the max line width (eg: 8 chars as you say).

Then, you can use

```
sed 's/./&|/9' <padded.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: The OP is ambiguous s/he says 9th but perhaps means 8th character? However the padding can be achieved at the same time, like so: `sed ':a;s/./&|/8;t;s/$/ /;ta' file`.

Answer (score 1):

Hard-coding the output field width:

```
$ awk '{printf "%-*s|\n",8,$0}' file
dog     |
fish    |
elephant|
...     |
```

or specifying the output field width as an argument:

```
$ awk -v wid=8 '{printf "%-*s|\n",wid,$0}' file
dog     |
fish    |
elephant|
...     |
```

or dynamically determining the output field width from the input field widths:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{lgth=length($0); wid=(lgth > wid ? lgth : wid); next} {printf "%-*s|\n",wid,$0}' file file
dog     |
fish    |
elephant|
...     |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to further process the records, it might be a good idea to actually make the `$0` 9 chars wide:

```
$ awk '{$0=$0 sprintf("%" 9-length() "s","|")}1' file
```

Output:

```
dog     |
fish    |
elephant|
...     |
```